# CSS divs side-by-side

Tags: css, html, css-float

I realize that already there is a lot of material on here pertaining to this issue, but I still am having trouble placing three divs side-by-side rather than stacked on top of each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/wkQv6/

```
<body>
    <div id='boom'>

    <div id='menutab' class='navbar'>
    Menu
        </div>
    <div class='navbar' id='storytab'>
    Our Story
    </div>
    <div class='navbar' id='contacttab'>
        Contact
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

#boom{background-image:url(http://therealchicagoonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Buca-di-Beppo-table_setting2.jpg);
text-align:center;
height:1000px;
width:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-top:0px;}

div.navbar{width:100px;
    float:left;

    display:inline-block;
background-color:black;
opacity:.7;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    height:25px;
    border-radius:0px;
    border-right:white;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:25px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/wkQv6/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS `left property`, left property sets the left edge of an element,Try this code:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/R6Tg4/)**:

CSS:

```
 #menutab
    {
    left:100px;
    }
    #storytab
    {
    left:250px;
    }
    #contacttab
    {
     left:400px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your css as below

```
#boom{background-image:url(http://therealchicagoonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03
/Buca-di-Beppo-table_setting2.jpg);
text-align:center;
height:1000px;
width:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-top:0px;}



div {
    float:left;
    padding-right:10px;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: Fixing position of div will overwrite them on each other

Answer (score 0):

`Position:fixed;` is the reason for your problem

Change the `CSS` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

Added a wrapper around menu items

```
<div id='boom'>
    <div class="menu">
        <div id='menutab' class='navbar'>Menu</div>
        <div class='navbar' id='storytab'>Our Story</div>
        <div class='navbar' id='contacttab'>Contact</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

Change `position to relative` and if you want it in center just add the menu css as shown beow, now the menu items will be in center irrespective of screen size, no hard coded px is required

```
.menu {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.navbar {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:.7;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    height:25px;
    border-radius:0px;
    border-right:white;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:25px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/fY9GY/)

Answer (score 0):

You need small change in your css

inside this

```
div.navbar{

   Remove position:fixed;

}
```

Its working fine